# Why does un-commenting the last sentence move the period to the new line?

Tags: listings

The last sentence in the MWE below is commented out. This paragraph then renders just fine.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[left=1.50in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
     frameround=fttt
    ,language=SQL
    ,numbers=left
    ,breaklines=true
    ,showstringspaces=false
    ,basicstyle=\small
}

You probably noticed that I declared all dynamic SQL variables as \lstinline[columns=fixed]{nvarchar(max)}. Sometimes it would be an overkill, but doing so relieves me from a burden of picking length for the declaration. Maximum width will accommodate virtually any dynamic SQL out there. %If it has to be merged from several variables, each of them should be declared similarly.

\end{document}
```

But if I un-comment the last sentence, then the period after the inline listing moves onto the new line:

[image]

What am I doing wrong with the inline listing?

PS: I had instances where when an inline listing wrapped onto the new line, a space between the words was at the beginning of the new line instead of not being rendered at all or beling left at the end of the first line. But I edited those examples one way or another and no longer have any to present here. That sounds like a related issue.

Comment: The output with `columns=fixed` is awful.

Comment: I know, but that was the only method recommended to me earlier, which rendered the inline listings same as the block listings. W/o that they were being rendered same as surrounding text.

Comment: That's why usually a monospaced font is used for listings.

Comment: Why is it not used here?

Comment: Because by default `listings` uses the text font; look for `basicstyle` in the documentation.

Comment: Now I recall why I did not use `\ttfamily` for the `basicstyle`: it rendered ugly and overly wide block listings. And now that I tried it again, it is clear that it is not fixing the problem at hand.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be feature of `breaklines=true` that breakpoints are added at the end of the inline listing. So the simplest thing is

```
\lstinline[columns=fixed,breaklines=false]{nvarchar(max)}.
```

but if you want to allow breaks within the listing, but not at the end, I think less simple things (changing listings internals) would be needed.

The last sentence is more or less unrelated, other than the fact that TeX considers the entire paragraph when choosing linebreaks and in the paragraph as posted the linebreak before the `.` is not chosen (but it is a legal breakpoint always)

---

OK so I had in mind something like `\zz` below which removes the final breakpoint but it doesn't really help as there are breakpoints everywhere (eg around the `)` and in this case, it doesn't make the `.` stay on the line, the listing just breaks in a (technically) different place.  However listings adds all its breakpoints as `\discretionary` which means that you can tune the desirability of breaking there by setting `\exhyphenpenalty` (100 seems a good value, the default value is 50) this has to be set at the *paragraph* level (so most easily for the whole document). If you just set it locally around the inline listing it has no effect.

This will also make line breaks at `foo-bar` slightly less favoured, but it will not affect the linebreaking at normal implicit hyphens when tex hyphenates a word automatically.

the last section shows that linebreaking is allowed, although the setting has prevented breaking in the test paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[left=1.50in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
     frameround=fttt
    ,language=SQL
    ,numbers=left
    ,breaklines=true
    ,showstringspaces=false
    ,basicstyle=\small
}

\def\zz{\leavevmode\afterassignment\zzz\setbox0\vbox}

\def\zzz{\aftergroup\zzzz\noindent}
\def\zzzz{\setbox0\vbox{\unvbox0 \setbox2=\lastbox\global\setbox1\hbox{\unhbox2\unskip\unskip}}%
\unhbox1 }


%\showoutput

\smallskip\noindent\textbf{original}

You probably noticed that I declared all dynamic SQL variables as \lstinline[columns=fixed]{nvarchar(max)}. Sometimes it would be an overkill, but doing so relieves me from a burden of picking length for the declaration. Maximum width will accommodate virtually any dynamic SQL out there. If it has to be merged from several variables, each of them should be declared similarly.

\smallskip\noindent\textbf{linebreak}

You probably noticed that I declared all dynamic SQL variables as \lstinline[columns=fixed]{nvarchar(max)}.\linebreak Sometimes it would be an overkill, but doing so relieves me from a burden of picking length for the declaration. Maximum width will accommodate virtually any dynamic SQL out there. If it has to be merged from several variables, each of them should be declared similarly.

\smallskip\noindent\textbf{hbox}

You probably noticed that I declared all dynamic SQL variables as \hbox{\lstinline[columns=fixed]{nvarchar(max)}}. Sometimes it would be an overkill, but doing so relieves me from a burden of picking length for the declaration. Maximum width will accommodate virtually any dynamic SQL out there. If it has to be merged from several variables, each of them should be declared similarly.

\smallskip\noindent\textbf{breaklines=false}

You probably noticed that I declared all dynamic SQL variables as \lstinline[columns=fixed,breaklines=false]{nvarchar(max)}. Sometimes it would be an overkill, but doing so relieves me from a burden of picking length for the declaration. Maximum width will accommodate virtually any dynamic SQL out there. If it has to be merged from several variables, each of them should be declared similarly.

\smallskip\noindent\textbf{zz}

You probably noticed that I declared all dynamic SQL variables as \zz{\lstinline[columns=fixed]{nvarchar(max)}}. Sometimes it would be an overkill, but doing so relieves me from a burden of picking length for the declaration. Maximum width will accommodate virtually any dynamic SQL out there. If it has to be merged from several variables, each of them should be declared similarly.


\noindent\textbf{check zz breaking}

 a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
 a a a a a a a aa a a a a a a a
\lstinline[columns=fixed]{g g g g g g g g g g g g }.

 a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
 a a a a a a a aa a a a a a a a
\zz{\lstinline[columns=fixed]{g g g g g g g g g g g g }}.


\noindent\textbf{penalty at discretionary}

\exhyphenpenalty100 

You probably noticed that I declared all dynamic SQL variables as \lstinline[columns=fixed]{nvarchar(max)}. Sometimes it would be an overkill, but doing so relieves me from a burden of picking length for the declaration. Maximum width will accommodate virtually any dynamic SQL out there. If it has to be merged from several variables, each of them should be declared similarly.



\noindent\textbf{check  breaking with penalty}


 a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
 a a a a a a a aa a a a a a a a
\lstinline[columns=fixed]{g g g g g g g g g g g g }.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Sigh]. Changing the verbiage of surrounding text slightly sounds like a less intrusive alternative.

Comment: @ajeh I could look at the weekend (not now) perhaps to see if it is easy to modify listings not to add the final breakpoint. ping here if you'd be interested in that (otherwise I probably won't bother:-)

Comment: Of course I would! The working inline listings should be welcomed by more than just me.

Comment: @ajeh answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\hbox{\lstinline[columns=fixed]{nvarchar(max)}.}
```

to solve your problem. It works whether or not the last line is present.

Comment: This has the same possible disadvantage as the solution I suggested, in that it prevents all linebreaking, not just at the end, it also should not be used at the start of a paragraph (not an issue in this example, but might be for other examples)

Comment: @David, I did not see your solution when I posted mine. I agree that our solutions have the same possible disadvantage of preventing all linebreaking, which I believe is desired in this instance, although perhaps not for all occurrences.

Comment: It sounds like there really is no solution, other than to to try to re-write each affected paragraph so that justification changes ever so slightly and the dot jumps back where it belongs. I cannot use the inline listings that do not break :(